# The vulnerability of Security Misconfiguration (Cookie without Secure Flag) is found

Tags: session-cookies, jsessionid

The reported vulnerability of Security Misconfiguration (Cookie without Secure Flag) is found valid  is reported by the security team.I am using spring mvc. TO mitigate this security i am trying to use servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
to fix the issue, the application is not getting started. I am using WebSphare server to deploy the application.

TO mitigate this security i am trying to use servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);